# Por que no puedo ejecutar programas .py desde terminal en Visual Studio Code Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ubuntu

Hola a todos y muchas gracias :) de antemano!! mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo instalado Visual Studio Code como pueden observar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando doy click aqui
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

solo me aparece la terminal de visual studio vacia
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo tengo instalados esos 2 plugins uno para un tema y el otro para poder correr python desde la terminal de Visual Studio, ya intente de todo reiniciar los plugins,desinstalarlos y volverlos a instalar,sin embargo esto no parece funcionar,cuando me funcionaba perfectamente bien,ya me habia pasado y el problema se habia corregido solo,simplemente que ahora ya no se quita
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para finalizar los .py se ejecutan correctamente desde consola como se puede observar aqui :D!!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les agradecere bastante su respuesta ;D !!

Comment: Se puede modificar el archivo de configuración settings.json, y establecer específicamente la ruta del ejecutable de python con la variable `defaultInterpreterPath` aqui viene documentación para esa y otras opciones para python https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference. La gran ventaja es que puedes especificarlo por proyecto cuando creas una carpeta `.vscode` con el archivo `settings.json` así eso afecta solamente a el proyecto en cuestión en vez de que sea configuración global.

Answer (score 0):

Por fin logre solucionarlo, lo que hice fue desinstalar la versión que te dan en el centro de software de ubuntu, me fui directamente a la pagina de Visual Studio Code e instale la ultima versión con el archivo .deb que te descargas para la version de linux, sorpresa ya quedo listo todo :D !!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]